# Output this string from the `kolmogorov-complexity` tag info page

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

[kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) is one of the tags on this site, representing challenges that test how much code is needed to output a given fixed result (usually a piece of text). The [info page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/kolmogorov-complexity/info) for this tag lists the string `4c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y39umgw5q85s7uraqbjfd` as an example of a string with a high Kolmogorov complexity, stating that printing this string literally is probably the shortest way to output it. I would like to test this statement, and thus your challenge is to output this string, without using a literal representation of it.

### Rules

- You must write a full program that takes no input, and outputs exactly the result string, with a single optional trailing newline. Output may be in any format allowed by default IO rules (writing to STDOUT, writing to a file, displaying to the screen, etc)
- No submitting the trivial solution of your language's equivalent of `print "4c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y39umgw5q85s7uraqbjfd"`, however, I will create a community wiki answer to list trivial solutions for comparison, so if you answer in a language not added to that answer, please edit that language's trivial solution (if it exists) into that post.
- Use of built-ins is allowed, if your language somehow has a built-in that contains or can easily generate this string, I would love to see that.

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest bytecount is best score, but please also list the difference in length between your bytecount and the bytecount of your language's trivial solution with your score.

Comment: What exactly counts as *not* a trivial solution? Hardcoding a list of codepoints and converting them to characters before printing? Is `print "4c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y"+"39umgw5q85s7uraqbjfd"` different enough to not be a trivial solution? Given that the string is chosen to have a high Kolmogorov complexity, I doubt it has any significant patterns that can be exploited, so every solution is likely to be some variation on hard-coding the string.

Comment: @DLosc I would say a list of codepoints is not trivial, and there may even be some ways to represent that more compactly than a literal string, but concatenating string literals is no different from using one literal

Comment: It is my opinion that rule 2 is unclear and effectively un-enforcable.  If this rule remains as is, I at least, will not be considering flags to delete invalid answers to this question.  There is just no way to consistently and objectively judge whether an answer meets rule 2.

Comment: The typical way of handling this is not to disallow trivial solutions, but just to discourage them, and make the community wiki answer. A hard rule is unclear (this is something that should have been brought up in the sandbox, sorry for that).

Comment: I agree with everyone. My suggestion is to simply encourage non-trivial answers, instead of outright banning them. It seems the voters agree with us.

Comment: Since the challenge is closed and I don't see it being re-opened anytime soon: 34 bytes 05AB1E answer: [try it online](https://tio.run/##AUQAu/9vc2FiaWX//@KAokXDhEogwrdNQMOrNl3CrM6jP8WSU8K4w4/QuOKJoMOqypJ7N8OOwqlE4oCixb5oQcKrw4XQsv9K/w) - Compressed integer `21514837667647952494674995137164218921462234474643402697091353` converted to custom-base `"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` (basically converted to a base-36 list and indexed into this string).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##AT4Awf9vc2FiaWX//@KAokXDhEogwrdNQMOrNl3CrM6jP8WSU8K4w4/QuOKJoMOqypJ7N8OOwqlE4oCi4oKGQmz//w) with normal base conversion

Comment: @ovs Ah, of course. I've been using so much list-based base-conversion in 05AB1E lately, I forgot about the regular base builtins. 

Answer (score 4):

## Trivial Solutions

If you answer this question and the trivial solution to this problem is not currently listed here, please edit it into this post, to serve as a point of comparison against non-trivial solutions in that language. For purposes of clarity, the trivial solution to this problem is defined as your language's equivalent of a `print` statement, plus your language's equivalent of a string literal, containing `4c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y39umgw5q85s7uraqbjfd`, and being passed to the `print` statement, plus whatever boilerplate is necessary to make it a full program.

When adding a language to this, please format with a level three heading containing the language name and bytecount (formatting: `### Language Name, XX bytes ###`). Follow this with a codeblock (formatting: ```` ``` code here ``` ````) containing the code of the trivial solution. Please try to keep the list in alphabetical order by language name.

**Place solutions below this line:**

---

#### 05AB1E, [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fySTZMMs0yajAILnMpNywwqKowqjS2LI0N73ctNDCtNi8tCixMCkrLeX/fwA)

```
"4c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y39umgw5q85s7uraqbjfd
```

#### Charcoal, [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJJNkwyzTJqMAgucyk3LDCoqjCqNLYsjQ3vdy00MK02Ly0KLEwKSstRUnT@v///7plOQA)

```
”E#-¡2e·ⅉÀθº,"ＧＥσＧ>υ[C=↥↗μω⮌ψ
```

It's a compressed string literal, but it's still a string literal, so I guess this counts as a trivial solution. The link is to the equivalent Verbose Charcoal, which is an even more trivial solution, but the Charcoal deverbosifier helpfully prints the actual solution before executing it.

#### Java 8, [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY7LDoIwFET3fsUNK1hABCFiiP6BbEzcGBelPFIsBfoCYvj2WiKbm8ydzMxpkUZ@W34MpkgIuCPCvgcAwmTFa4QryDcJ8JCcsAZq99mTErSX2e96sEdIJAmGHBhcjfZvTozDNimi4Yh1PIVzyudoOV1U10zJmCbirDgai7YuHZNt@UEV1Ob3Gr21dxbC/Q@@3sjbARYhqy7olQwG60iXBbXLFKXezrKaHw)

```java
v->"4c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y39umgw5q85s7uraqbjfd"
```

#### Jelly, [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxyTZMMs0ySjAoPkMpNywwqLogqjSmPL0tz0ctNCC9Ni89KixMKkrLSU//8B)

```
“4c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y39umgw5q85s7uraqbjfd
```

#### Julia, [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69EQ8kk2TDLNMmowCC5zKTcsMKiqMKo0tiyNDe93LTQwrTYvLQosTApKy1FSfP/fwA)

```
print("4c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y39umgw5q85s7uraqbjfd")
```

#### Python 2, [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EySTZMMs0yajAILnMpNywwqKowqjS2LI0N73ctNDCtNi8tCixMCkrLUXp/38A)

```python
print"4c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y39umgw5q85s7uraqbjfd"
```

#### Python 3, [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ8kk2TDLNMmowCC5zKTcsMKiqMKo0tiyNDe93LTQwrTYvLQosTApKy1FSfP/fwA)

```python
print("4c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y39umgw5q85s7uraqbjfd")
```

#### Retina, [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fyyTZMMs0yajAILnMpNywwqKowqjS2LI0N73ctNDCtNi8tCixMCkrLeX/fwA)

```
4c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y39umgw5q85s7uraqbjfd
```

#### Rust, [61 bytes](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Ds7qgKDOvRFFDySTZMMs0yajAILnMpNywwqKowqjS2LI0N73ctNDCtNi8tCixMCkrLUVHSbP2/38A)

```rust
fn main(){print!("4c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y39umgw5q85s7uraqbjfd")}
```

#### APL, 42 bytes

```
'4c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y39umgw5q85s7uraqbjfd'
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>35</s>  34 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ØBḟØA“÷ȯḋ²÷Œmṗ)¿+¹ỊỴ7ĠYṖP0ṡẋœ{ỵC’ṃ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AU4Asf9qZWxsef//w5hC4bifw5hB4oCcw7fIr@G4i8Kyw7fFkm3huZcpwr8rwrnhu4rhu7Q3xKBZ4bmWUDDhuaHhuovFk3vhu7VD4oCZ4bmD//8)**

#### How?

```
ØBḟØA“...’ṃ - Main Link: no arguments
ØB          - base-62 digits = "0..9A..Za..z"
   ØA       - uppercase characters = "A..Z"
  ḟ         - filter-discard -> "0..9a..z"
     “...’  - big integer in a base 250 representation
          ṃ - base decompress (use the characters as base 62 digits of the integer)
            - implicit print
```

Comment: not bad! I did assume this sort of thing would be main thing I'd see for this question, built-in string compression from languages that can do that easily

Comment: This uses no built-in string compression, it uses two built-in literals (`ØB` and `ØA`) and a large integer. But, yes, I doubt you will get an answer that beats the purely trivial one that exploits a pattern in the data (since encoding that pattern is likely to be much longer than printing the data itself), unless that is also a built-in feature of the language itself ([Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum) style).

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 49 bytes

```julia
print(4,:c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y39umgw5q85s7uraqbjfd)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69Ew0THKtkwyzTJqMAgucyk3LDCoqjCqNLYsjQ3vdy00MK02Ly0KLEwKSstRfP/fwA)

Same length as the trivial solution. I guess it's not trivial ? And it's technically not concatenation. It prints the number 4 and then a [Symbol](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.Symbol) (technically not a string).

Feel free to debate whether this is too trivial or not

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 36 bytes

```
⍘⍘AN%)~:0+VJEkbeQYeRX!$2_[^}8g?\xγ³⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R7wwgcvRT1ayzMtAO83LNTkoNjEwNilBUMYqPjqu1SLePqTi3@dDmR41b//8HAA) Explanation: Converts the literal string `AN%)~:0+VJEkbeQYeRX!$2_[^}8g?\x` from base 95 (using printable ASCII) to base 35 (using `0-9a-y`).

If the compressed string literal form of the above literal string is allowed, then for 34 bytes:

```
⍘⍘“\`"Ｚζ﹪⊕↙84¤κq≡ＩT⁵⭆℅?R¤Ｂg÷φm⊙”γ³⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMpsTg1uATITEdmKjn6qWrWWRloh3m5ZielBkamBkUoqhjFR8fVWqTbx8RUKOkopGvqKBibampa////X7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Alternatively, the compressed string literal form of the numeric value of the base 35 conversion also results in 34 bytes:

```
⍘Ｉ”)¶＆Ｋ‖◨"Ｓγ]ιＪG÷φïzjμp⬤ＸχφωqE·”³⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZLCsIwEADQq5SuErAwk5nMB3d6AcEThCIqlBba4PXHvtWbP22ft7ZEPPbv2tOtHa9nP/tO93b0NCqaIoErOasKMwmwEWNBEnEsDsiiXMEL@RkoXgnNRMzGfBmo5nyNiOm3/AE) Link is to verbose version of code.

Comment: Both of these are longer than the Charcoal answer in the "trivial solutions" section.

Comment: @TheFifthMarshal But they are still shorter than the Charcoal program `4c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y39umgw5q85s7uraqbjfd`. I'm just not sure whether using built-in compression counts as trivial or not, so I'm erring on the side of safety and providing both options.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
»gtWŀż⌊l,∇ɖ∩꘍√ṘȮ∞*"Cβ1⋎ʀv@Ḃ»kakd+τ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCu2d0V8WAxbzijIpsLOKIh8mW4oip6piN4oia4bmYyK7iiJ4qXCJDzrIx4ouOyoB2QOG4gsK7a2FrZCvPhCIsIiIsIiJd)

-1 thanks to @whqwert

Ez

```
»gtWŀż⌊l,∇ɖ∩꘍√ṘȮ∞*"Cβ1⋎ʀv@Ḃ»kakd+τ # Full program
                                 τ # Convert the number to base len(str) using the number...
»gtWŀż⌊l,∇ɖ∩꘍√ṘȮ∞*"Cβ1⋎ʀv@Ḃ»       # 149288472330050833510329217157030174401240445325930074868876423
                            kakd+  # And the string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
```

Comment: [34 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?code=%C2%BBgtW%C5%80%C5%BC%E2%8C%8Al%2C%E2%88%87%C9%96%E2%88%A9%EA%98%8D%E2%88%9A%E1%B9%98%C8%AE%E2%88%9E*%22C%CE%B21%E2%8B%8E%CA%80v%40%E1%B8%82%C2%BBkakd%2B%CF%84)